# Convert to double failed if the value is null or empty

Tags: c#

I write a method to convert the string into double,here is the code

```
public double convertToDouble(string number)
{
    string temp = number;
    if (number.Contains("x"))
    {
        int locationE = number.IndexOf("x");
        string exponent = number.Substring(locationE + 5, number.Length - (locationE + 5));
        temp = number.Substring(0, locationE - 1) + "E" + exponent;
    }

    return Convert.ToDouble(temp);
}
```

But if the temp variable passed in as null or empty string, the conversion will fail. How could i write this part.

Comment: Testing with string.IsNullOrEmpty and return? And this leads to: what do you want to return in case of null or empty string?

Comment: Test the variable for being null or empty string first?

Comment: As others have said - you should test the string before converting. Also, using Convert.ToDouble is only good to use if you know for a fact the string is in double format. I would look into double.TryParse()

Answer (score 5):

Why do you want to write a new method for this purpose, while you could use the more safest one, `double.TryParse`.

```
double number;

// The numberStr is the string you want to parse
if(double.TryParse(numberStr, out number))
{
    // The parsing succeeded.
}
```

If you don't like the above approach and you want to stick with your method, then the only option I see is to throw an exception.

```
public double convertToDouble(string number)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(number))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The input cannot be null, empty string or consisted only of of white space characters", "number");
    }

    string temp = number;
    if (number.Contains("x"))
    {
        int locationE = number.IndexOf("x");
        string exponent = number.Substring(locationE + 5, number.Length - (locationE + 5));
        temp = number.Substring(0, locationE - 1) + "E" + exponent;
    }
    return Convert.ToDouble(temp);
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the answer, so +1 to compensate. You beat me to the answer while I was writing mine, but let mine because I wanted to tip on the string replacement part too :-)

Comment: @Jcl Thank you very much :) It's sad to see this in our community. We should all had as a plan to get better from this community. I don't see any reasonable reason in voting down answers or question without explaining what's wrong. In addition to this the current question has taken -3 points  without anyone of the 3 persons who downvoted to give an explanation to the OP what's wrong, if there is any wrong at all.

Comment: I had that happen many times, so I feel you there. Wished downvoting needed a comment, even a small one :-)

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what do you want to happen when the number can't be converted.

You could try this:

```
public double convertToDouble(string number)
{
    string temp = number;
    if (number.Contains("x"))
    {
        int locationE = number.IndexOf("x");
        string exponent = number.Substring(locationE + 5, number.Length - (locationE + 5));
        temp = number.Substring(0, locationE - 1) + "E" + exponent;
    }
    double returnDouble;
    if(double.TryParse(temp, out returnDouble))
      return returnDouble;

    // Return whatever or throw an exception, etc.
    return 0;
}
```

As a further tip, it looks like you are converting something like `[number] x 10^[exponent]` to `[number]E[exponent]`, if so, this could be easily converted as:

```
public double convertToDouble(string number)
{
    if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(number)) 
       return 0; // or throw exception, or whatever

    // Instead of all those "IndexOf" and "Substrings"
    var temp = number.Replace("x 10^", "E");

    double returnDouble;
    if(double.TryParse(temp, out returnDouble))
      return returnDouble;

    // Return whatever or throw an exception, etc.
    return 0;
}
```

This could be further prettified without hurting readability, but I'll leave that to you

Comment: For the string replacement (+1) from me